# Trivial full-fledged variant for constexpr (proof of concept)

Tags: c++, variant-type

I want to show you how to implement `variant` like `boost::variant`, but almost for `constexpr`, not runtime:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< std::size_t i >
using I = std::integral_constant< std::size_t, i >;

template< std::size_t i >
struct index : I< i > {};

template< bool ...b >
struct get_i;
template<>
struct get_i<> {};
template< bool ...rest >
struct get_i< true, rest... > : index< sizeof...(rest) > {};
template< bool ...rest >
struct get_i< false, rest... > : get_i< rest... > {};
template< typename ...types >
using get_di = get_i< std::is_default_constructible< types >::value... >;

template< typename type, typename ...types >
struct i_at {};
template< typename type, typename ...rest >
struct i_at< type, type, rest... > : index< sizeof...(rest) > {};
template< typename type, typename first, typename ...rest >
struct i_at< type, first, rest... > : i_at< type, rest... > {};
template< typename type, typename ...types >
using i_at_t = typename i_at< type, types... >::type;

template< bool td, typename ...types >
struct C;

template< bool td >
struct C< td >
{
    void destruct(std::size_t) { ; }
};

template< typename first, typename ...rest >
struct C< true, first, rest... >
{
    using head = first;
    using tail = C< true, rest... >;
    
    union
    {
        head head_;
        tail tail_;
    };
    
    constexpr C() = default;
    
    template< typename ...A >
    constexpr C(I< (1 + sizeof...(rest)) >, A &&... a)
        : head_(std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }
    
    template< typename ...A >
    constexpr C(A &&... a)
        : tail_(std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }
     
    constexpr operator first const & () const { return head_; }
    constexpr operator first & () { return head_; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return tail_; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return tail_; }
};

template< typename first, typename ...rest >
struct C< false, first, rest... >
{
    using head = first;
    using tail = C< false, rest... >;
    
    union
    {
        head head_;
        tail tail_;
    };
    
    constexpr C() = default;
    
    C(C const &) = default;
    C(C &) = default;
    C(C &&) = default;
    C & operator = (C const &) = default;
    C & operator = (C &) = default;
    C & operator = (C &&) = default;
    
    ~C() { /*tail_.~tail();*/ }

    void destruct(std::size_t w) { (w == sizeof...(rest) + 1) ? head_.~head() : tail_.destruct(w); }
    
    template< typename ...A >
    constexpr C(I< (1 + sizeof...(rest)) >, A &&... a)
        : head_(std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }
    
    template< typename ...A >
    constexpr C(A &&... a)
        : tail_(std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }
     
    constexpr operator first const & () const { return head_; }
    constexpr operator first & () { return head_; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return tail_; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return tail_; }
};

template< bool td, bool tdc, typename ...types >
struct D;

template< typename ...types >
struct D< true, true, types... >
{
    using storage = C< true, types... >;
    
    std::size_t w;
    storage c;
    
    constexpr std::size_t which() const { return (w == 0) ? sizeof...(types) : w; }
    
    constexpr D() = default;
    
    template< typename i, typename ...A >
    constexpr D(i, A &&... a)
        : w(i::value)
        , c(i{}, std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }

    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return c; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return c; }
};

template< typename ...types >
struct D< false, true, types... >
{
    using storage = C< false, types... >;
    
    std::size_t w;
    storage c;
    
    constexpr std::size_t which() const { return (w == 0) ? sizeof...(types) : w; }
    
    constexpr D() = default;
    
    D(D const &) = default;
    D(D &) = default;
    D(D &&) = default;
    D & operator = (D const &) = default;
    D & operator = (D &) = default;
    D & operator = (D &&) = default;

    ~D() { if (w != 0) c.destruct(w); }
    
    template< typename i, typename ...A >
    constexpr D(i, A &&... a)
        : w(i::value)
        , c(i{}, std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }

    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return c; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return c; }
};

template< typename ...types >
struct D< true, false, types... >
{
    using storage = C< true, types... >;
    
    std::size_t w;
    storage c;
    
    constexpr std::size_t which() const { return w; }
    
    using di = get_di< types..., void >;
    
    constexpr D() : D(typename di::type{}) { ; }
    
    template< typename i, typename ...A >
    constexpr D(i, A &&... a)
        : w(i::value)
        , c(i{}, std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }

    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return c; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return c; }
};

template< typename ...types >
struct D< false, false, types... >
{
    using storage = C< false, types... >;
    
    std::size_t w;
    storage c;
    
    constexpr std::size_t which() const { return w; }
    
    using di = get_di< types..., void >;
    
    constexpr D() : D(typename di::type{}) { ; }
    
    D(D const &) = default;
    D(D &) = default;
    D(D &&) = default;
    D & operator = (D const &) = default;
    D & operator = (D &) = default;
    D & operator = (D &&) = default;
    
    ~D() { c.destruct(w); }
    
    template< typename i, typename ...A >
    constexpr D(i, A &&... a)
        : w(i::value)
        , c(i{}, std::forward< A >(a)...)
    { ; }

    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T const & () const { return c; }
    template< typename T >
    constexpr operator T & () { return c; }
};

template< typename ...types >
using D_t = D< (std::is_trivially_destructible< types >::value && ...), (std::is_trivially_default_constructible< types >::value && ...), types... >;

template< bool dc >
struct DC;

template<>
struct DC< true >
{
    constexpr DC() = default;
    constexpr DC(void *) { ; }
};

template<>
struct DC< false >
{
    constexpr DC() = delete;
    constexpr DC(void *) { ; }
};

template< typename ...types >
using DC_t = DC< (std::is_default_constructible< types >::value || ...) >;

template< typename ...types >
class V
    : DC_t< types... >
{
    using dc = DC_t< types... >;
    using storage = D_t< types... >;
    
    storage d;
    
public :

    template< typename T >
    using i_at_t = i_at_t< T, types..., void >;

    constexpr
    std::size_t which() { return d.which(); }
    
    constexpr V() = default;
    
    template< typename T, typename i = i_at_t< T > >
    constexpr V(T && x) : dc({}), d(i{}, std::forward< T >(x)) { ; }

    template< typename T, typename = i_at_t< T > >
    explicit constexpr operator T const & () const { return d; }
    template< typename T, typename = i_at_t< T > >
    explicit constexpr operator T & () { return d; }
    
    template< typename T, typename = i_at_t< T > >
    constexpr V & operator = (T && x) { return (*this = V(std::forward< T >(x))); }
    
    template< std::size_t i, typename ...A >
    constexpr V(index< i >, A &&... a) : dc({}), d(I< i >{}, std::forward< A >(a)...) { ; }
};

inline constexpr bool test()
{
    {
        struct A {};
        V< int, double, A > v{};
        // ^    ^       ^
        // 3    2       1
        if (v.which() != 3) return false;
        v = 2;
        if (static_cast< int & >(v) != 2) return false;
        v = A{};
        if (v.which() != 1) return false;
        v = -1.0;
        if (v.which() != 2) return false;
        if (static_cast< double & >(v) < -1.0) return false;
        if (static_cast< double & >(v) > -1.0) return false;
    }
    { // emplacement constructor
        struct A { constexpr A(int) { ; } };
        struct B {};
        struct C {};
        using U = V< A, B, C >;
        U u{};
        if (u.which() != 2) return false;
        U v{index< 1 >{}};
        if (v.which() != 1) return false;
        U w{index< 3 >{}, 1};
        if (w.which() != 3) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static_assert(test());
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e088093a83d6dc9f)

It still correct for arbitrary alternative types, but it provides full functionality only if all the alternative types are [TiviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). Now you can generate AST using compile time parsers (joke).

The functionality is:

- default constructor (for first leftmost default constructible alternative type, if any)
- conversion constructor
- copy/move-constructors
- copy/move-assignment operators.
- conversion ("from") operator (access to stored value)
- conversion assignment ("to") operator (can alter active member at even compile time)
- discriminator `which()`, indexing is right to left one-based
- emplace constructor

Please, don't criticize the naming. Current naming is just for brevity. Can I request a criticism of design flaws (or maybe there is another site for such requests?)?

#### ADDITIONAL:

There is one restriction on using `V` on the stack (automatic storage duration) or when it casted from sutiable sized and aligned storage using `reinterpret_cast`: it must be value-initialized (and, therefore, zero-initialized), nor default-initialized, the storage should be filled by zeros.